# On failure (if the app fails)

Tags: vb.net

I have an app and it fails randomly sometimes because my internet is not so fast (my app uses the webbrowser). How can I make my app restart itself it it fails? Or make my app click button1 on my form if it fails.

Comment: It sounds like you should be wrapping some I/O in some better error handling.  What specific block of code is failing and what exception is it throwing?  You should be able to catch the exception and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in the past.  I solved it by using scheduled tasks to start the app on a regular basis.  On Startup the new version would attempt to stop the old version and if that failed, (because it was hung) it would kill the process of the old program.